# Laravel DB class no table method on new project

Tags: php, laravel-5

I just can't figured out this issu; On a new Laravel project, I just can't use table method on DB class.

I use PhpStorm as EDI on OSX Sierra with Laravel 5.5.

Here my steps:

1. In terminal: Laravel new testproject
2. In terminal: composer install
3. In terminal: php artisan make:controller testdummy
4. In EDI:

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

   class testdummy extends Controller

   {
       //
       public function index(){
           DB::table('title')->insert([
               'label' => 'test1',
               'desc' => 'test2',
           ]);
       }
   }
   ```

The 'table' have a warning popup in EDI that say:

> 'Method table not found in Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB'.

And no insertion are made to database.

Have you some hints on where to look next to help me find the problem?

thanks,

Comment: Check your base Controller and find the code where you used those queries.

Comment: Regarding facades and autocompletion in the IDE, check out the [IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

Comment: You furthermore need to create the table first via [a migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations) to be able to insert rows.